# How to finally ignore a file in all sub-directories via .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore, git-add, rabbitvcs

I know there are lots of duplicate questions but I'm fully confused. I should admit I'm completely new to Git. I'm using RabbitVCS, However, I edit the .gitignore file using gedit manually. That's what I have done:

1. I have created a repository in Github.
2. I cloned it in my local computer using RabbitVCS.
3. I have pasted all files and folders of project into the repository.
4. I have created a `.gitignore` file in the root of repository which includes this pattern: `*~`.

**I haven't commited anything yet**.

I want to ignore all `~` and such other temp files in root and sub-directories. It ignores all files in root, but has no effect in sub-directories. When I want to commit using RabbitVCS, I can see them in the commit window.

I'm confusing because in Bazaar, we first add files, then commit them. But it Git, it seems we should just commit to add new files! Is it right?

What am I doing wrong? should I commit first?

Comment: You are doing it right. `*~` ignores all files ending in `~`, everywhere. Because pattern that does not include `/` is matched on filename, pattern that includes `/` is matched on path. How did you get the idea you need to do anything else?

Comment: In git, you have to add all changes you want to commit. However, `.gitignore` is taken from the work tree. It takes effect without committing it.

Comment: @JanHudec I can see ignored files in commit window of RabbitVCS. That's why I thought I need to do something else. In Bazaar, when I ignore a file, it won't show in add and commit window. I'm wondering if there is difference between Bazaar & Git which I don't understand.

Comment: Do you see them in output of `git status` on console as well?

Comment: @JanHudec No, but I think that's because II haven't run `git add` yet.

Comment: `git status` shows "untracked" files, which are the files that you _did not add_, but can. So if they don't show up there, you've ignored them as far as git is concerned and the problem is RabbitVCS.

Comment: But `git status` is not showing any file. It's just showing the file and folders in the root of repository.

Comment: If there are some unversioned files in a directory, but no versioned ones, it only shows the directory. But if there are only ignored files in a directory, it should not show it.

Answer (score 1):

From [the gitignore manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> A leading "**" followed by a slash means match in all directories. For example, "**/foo" matches file or directory "foo" anywhere, the same as pattern "foo". "**/foo/bar" matches file or directory "bar" anywhere that is directly under directory "foo".

As Jan Hudec writes, you can just use `*~`:

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/test/.git/
$ echo '*~' > .gitignore
$ mkdir -p some/deep/directory
$ touch some/deep/directory/test.txt
$ touch some/deep/directory/test.txt~
$ git add some/deep/directory/test.txt*
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
some/deep/directory/test.txt~
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

Comment: You mean I should use `**/*~` ?!

Comment: @Ali: No, you should use just `*~`!

Comment: `**/foo` ..., **the same as pattern `foo`**.